# Python - Efficiently find the set of all characters in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the set of all unique characters contained within a pandas DataFrame. One solution that works is given below:

```
from operator import add
set(reduce(add, map(unicode, df.values.flatten())))
```

However, the solution above takes a long time with large DataFrames. What are more efficient ways of doing this?

I am trying to find all unique characters in a pandas DataFrame so I can choose an appropriate delimiter when writing the DataFrame to disk as a csv.

Comment: Why not just let Pandas handle writing the DataFrame to a CSV file (`to_csv()`)? No need to choose the delimiter yourself - Pandas handles everything properly.

Comment: Yeah, to expand on previous comment, exactly what problem are you trying to solve?  Even if there is a comma inside a string, it shouldn't cause a problem since it will be output inside of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Learned this from Jeff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084382/unique-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

This should be doable using Pandas built-ins:

```
a = pd.DataFrame( data=np.random.randint(0,100000,(1000000,20)))

# now pull out unique values (less than a second for 2E7 data points)
b = pd.unique( a.values.ravel() )
```

Comment: I don't think that is what is asked for as poster seems to be looking for individual characters, not ovarall values.  E.g. 1.0 has a 1, 0, and period.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I was looking for the same thing and thought I'd share for anyone else looking.

This can be done very quickly with [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Use `unstack()` to get a list of all values in your dataframe. The result  even has a count of each character.

```
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.util.testing.rands_array(100, 100000),
                 'B': pd.util.testing.rands_array(100, 100000)})
Counter(''.join(df.unstack().values))
```

Timings:

```
%timeit Counter(''.join(df.unstack().values))
1.1 s ± 38.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```