# csvstat takes a much longer time to run than pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, command-line

I am trying to get the number of unique values in a specific column in a csv (~10 GB) and am looking for the fastest way to do that. I expected command line tools like `csvstat` to run faster than pandas, but:

```
def get_uniq_col_count(colname):
    df = pd.read_csv('faults_all_main_dp_1_joined__9-4-15.csv', engine='c', usecols=[colname], nrows = 400000)
    df.columns = ['col']
    return len(set(df.col.values)), list(set(df.col.values))

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
count, uniq = get_uniq_col_count('model')
print(datetime.datetime.now() - t1)

# 0:00:04.386585
```

vs.

```
$ time csvcut -c model faults_all_main_dp_1_joined__9-4-15.csv | head -n 400000 | csvstat --unique
3
real    1m3.343s
user    1m3.212s
sys     0m0.237s
```

(I am doing the header, because I let `csvstat` run on the whole dataset, went out for lunch, came back, and it’s still running. It took `pandas` 50 sec to finish.)

I wonder if I am doing something wrong, and in general, if there is a way to speed up the process. (There are about 5 million rows to read through for each column.)

Comment: I never tried csvstat, but I must say that I'm also quite satisfied with pandas speed

Comment: Assuming you checked that pandas is producing the correct results, then it sounds like you don't really have a problem with speed if it processes all that data in 50s, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have over 1400 columns in each csv.

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising. 'csvtools' are written entirely in python and do not use any optimization tricks. In particular, 'csvstat' will read entire table into memory and store multiple copies of it as regular python list. This has huge overhead -- both in memory and in the garbage collector time.

Oh the other hand, pandas uses numpy, which means that the whole column uses only a few python objects, and almost no memory overhead. You may be able to make your program slightly faster by using pandas-specific unique method ([Find unique values in a Pandas dataframe, irrespective of row or column location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084382/unique-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe))

If you are going to be doing this a lot, convert the data to a more efficient format. This page: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization/ shows that if once you convert your data to HDF5, it will be much faster to load.